# How to fire an event when a Search through ctrl+f happened in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, greasemonkey, mozilla

I am writing a script for Mozilla to done following requirement.When user click ctrl+f and search some text in a web page through,
If it is found that should be added with yellow background. I am strucked in start to write this script. Please someone help me with the idea. I am writing it through "greasemonkey".
 If a user search through Mozilla's native findbar. If it is found that should be highlighted with some color. Even if another search happens old highlight should not be removed.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Why would a user want this instead of Mozilla's native implementation of find?

Comment: posting your code will increase chance to get help

Comment: @Sam Dutton If a user search through Mozilla's native findbar. If it is found that should be highlighted with some color. Even if another search happens old highlight should not be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work...

```
ctrlPressed = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e){

   if(e.keyCode == 17){                           //17 is "ctrl"
         ctrlPressed = true;
   }

   if(ctrlPressed && e.keyCode == 70){            //70 is "f"
       alert("Page is being searched");
   }

});


$(document).keyup(function(e){

   if(e.keyCode == 17){ 
         ctrlPressed = false;
   }

});
```

...but I suspect there may be a more straightforward way.

Comment: @learner You mean you want to prevent it from running in other browsers? Also, I don't think they would be able to search the page in the first place if it wasn't in focus.